# Android/Java :как правильно хранить url/http ссылки?

Tags: java, android

Собственно сам додумалься тока  до такого варианта:
В файле формата XML(например в /res/values/string.xml)создаю строковый ресурс,например
`<string name="URL_ADDRESS">https://www.google.ru</string>`
А затем в коде ,по мере надобности, их извлекаю

```
String URL_ADDRESS;

.......................
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    URL_ADDRESS = getResources().getString(R.string.URL_ADDRESS);
```

Но если в приложении таких ссылок будет допустим 20-30,будет ли это правильным,и правильно ли вообще так делать?

Comment: на этот счет нет стандарта. Вы можете хранить их как константы, или как строковые ресурсы (так, как сейчас). Ваш вопрос вообще не имеет смысла - каждый делает так, как ему удобнее

Answer (score 4):

Тут скорее вопрос и специфики вашего приложения, и вообще общепринятых способов хранения данных в Android. Из своего опыта - напрямую в файле что-то хранят очень редко. Потому что существуют куда более удобные и гибкие способы, как правило. Это SharedPreferences или же база данных. Из вашего лаконичного вопроса трудно сделать окончательное заключение, но мне кажется, что вам больше подойдёт база данных, нежели всё остальное. SharedPreferences чаще используются для хранения каких-то настроек, или прочих компактных данных, базы данных - для больших массивов данных. А дальше - вам решать.